# Dropping Out Means You're BlackListed

Tags: graduate-school, quitting

Would students who drop out before they take any exam be blacklisted by the (prestigious) university?

Especially if those students have shown a resentment and a disagreement with the arrangement of the academic program they're enrolled in.

Or is it normal to be contacted by the university inciting the student to apply again?

Comment: So far as I know, no university _bothers_ to keep track of students who drop out, certainly not with any hostility. Sure, some faculty may remember students who had "issues", but will not at all necessarily "harbor a grudge". It's more like dealing with "kids with issues", than colleagues, despite the (unwise) pretensions broadcast on some web sites. Even kids who were combative, etc, are implicitly forgiven, _contingently_, under the understanding that people (can!!!) change enormously in those years from 18 to 20-something... not to mention later...

Comment: It's doubtful that they care about you enough to blacklist you _or_ proactively invite you to reapply.

Comment: Unless it's a very small college, I don't think they care that much. They have too many things to do, why bother with a drop out student?

Answer (score 8):

> Would students who drop out before they take any exam be blacklisted by the (prestigious) university?

No.  Students drop out of a class or school frequently.  If it was recent - then you are likely still "admitted" and can register next term.

> Or is it normal to be contacted by the university inciting the student to apply again?

I'm not sure they'll ask you to come back - they might, but it is up to you do work on getting back in.

I suggest checking your status on-line, or talk to someone in the registrar's office.
While a very prestigious school has a thousand students lined up behind you to take your place, it is likely that if they admitted you in the first place, they'll be happy to keep you.  If you do it again, then they might think less of you.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I was really thrilled to start this academic program as an international student. I was disappointed after the first 48 hours. I tried to survive there for almost 6 weeks till I did officially drop out. I had a conversation with a teacher there who invited me to discuss the matter, and suddenly asked me if I was going to comeback. 4 months later, their enrollment office sent me an email telling deadlines are close enough, please apply before this date ...

Comment: Then it looks like you can go back if you want to.  Just be prepared for the world of "academia".  It is very different than other places.

Answer (score 3):

Until this moment, I've never heard of anyone "...resenting the arrangement of the academic program they're enrolled in..." That seems...unusual.

People temporarily withdraw from schools for many legitimate reasons very frequently. It's not unusual. They don't have any difficulty returning, for example, the following semester.

In this case, the reason suggested is what concerns me. It suggests there may have been some animosity or "words exchanged" with the wrong people.

Comment: Maybe I should change resentment to disagreement. Some softcore courses professors didn't accept my criticism of the way they "teach". I was an international student, but to my surprise, a local student also expressed how he suffered because of those teachers. I left because I lost complete serenity (I started to tremble a lot when I woke up in the morning - self battle between leaving and staying).

Comment: @HalfLife Was it a public speaking class? I have glossophobia, so ANY class that involves presentations would cause me to shiver and shake. There ought to be a law! http://www.glossophobia.com/

Comment: I was trembling because I hated being there.

Answer (score 1):

For what its worth I can sympathise OP.  If possible, it is a good idea to "try before you buy" -- but if you "try after you buy" and really don't like the result for whatever reason, sometimes you can still get your money back.  That is what warranties and exchange policies are all about in the commercial sector.  In the service sector, that is of course much harder to do.  Keep in mind that if you go back to the programme you left, you could waste a lot of time and money if it's still not a good fit.

My suggestion would be to take what you learned about yourself, and use that to find an arrangement that feels like a better fit.